# Problem with WCF-Service between Silverlight and Azure Cloud WebRole

Tags: silverlight, wcf, azure

I want to use a Silverlight application in a cloud on Azure. The communication between the Silverlight application and the WebRole is a WCF-Service with Basic-HTTP-Binding.
My problem is, that the communication doesn't work. I think the endpoint-address is not correct, but I'm not sure.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/) that will at least tell you if the end point is correct.
It should also help if there are any permissions issues.

Answer (score 1):

I found these [samples](http://code.msdn.com/wcfazure) cited by the [Silverlight Web Services team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/silverlightws/). The [Known Issues Wiki](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wcfazure/Wiki/View.aspx?title=KnownIssues&referringTitle=Home) is also very helpful. These examples use a binary HTTP binding instead of BasicHttpBinding but they get the job done.

If you are running Vista, like I am, You may need to register the WCF MIME types for IIS 7. You can do this be running a command prompt in elevated mode and executing this command:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation\ServiceModelReg.exe -i

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with linking to Webservices in Azure. I would check the endpoint in the Silverlight application and make sure it is the same as the port used in your Azure application.

I came across the same issue when working through the Azure Labs and rewrote Excercise 3 (using WCF) so that it would work - that is now available on CodeProject (http://www.codeproject.com/articles/34612/Getting-WCF-to-work-with-Azure.aspx).

I based that on a posting from David Burela's House-o-blog and his description of the problem can be found on his blog.